# Name order for tags like [hayao-miyazaki]

Tags: discussion, tags

In tags that are the names of real Japanese people, in which order should we put the people's names?

That is, should we have [hayao-miyazaki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hayao-miyazaki) (Western order) or [miyazaki-hayao](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miyazaki-hayao) (Japanese order)?

Note that this post is not about the way names should be ordered in questions, answers, or tag wikis - only in the names of tags themselves.

Comment: I call myself Madara Uchiha, and not Uchiha Madara, mainly because this is an English speaking site, and just like we write in English here, it's expected by users that we follow English naming conventions etc.

Answer (score 11):

As it stands, we already have the following tags, which seem to have evolved more or less organically:

- [hayao-miyazaki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hayao-miyazaki)
- [ken-akamatsu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ken-akamatsu) (okay, I changed this one from [akamatsu-ken](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akamatsu-ken) for consistency)
- [makoto-shinkai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/makoto-shinkai)
- [mamoru-hosoda](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mamoru-hosoda)
- [mamoru-oshii](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mamoru-oshii)
- [osamu-tezuka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osamu-tezuka)

All of these are in **Western order** (i.e. Given-Family).

I propose that we institute, as an Anime.SE policy, a strong preference that tags for real Japanese people continue to have their names in Western order unless there is a very compelling reason not to do so.

(We were already doing this, of course; the purpose of this post is basically to formalize the pre-existing practice for future reference.)

---

Note: we *could* add synonyms like [miyazaki-hayao](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miyazaki-hayao) pointing to [hayao-miyazaki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hayao-miyazaki), and it would certainly do no harm, but it's also not necessary - when you're searching for tags or entering tags on a new question, typing in "miyazaki" will bring up all tags that have "miyazaki" as a word, including [hayao-miyazaki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hayao-miyazaki), even though "miyazaki" isn't at the beginning of that tag.

If synonyms are implemented, this proposal should basically be read as requiring that the main/master tag be in Western order, with the synonym tag(s) being whatever else.

Comment: Couldn't we also just synonym them to each other?

Comment: @Dimitrimx See edit.